# How to disable the highlight on the line number in the sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

How do you disable the highlights on the line number in the sublime text?
[image]

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I think that's default behavior of every editor that displays line numbers. You can only disable *line highlighting*...

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in option for that (there might exist a plugin or two for that, though). All available options can be found in `Preferences`>`Settings`.
You could opt to go "all in" and highlight the entire "current" line;

> "highlight_line": true

If you just need to "unselect" the file, e.g. to make a screenshot or something, hit `Alt + Leftclick` to effectively remove the caret, and also the line number marking. However, that might only serve for this particular situation.

Why do you 'need' to remove the line numbering anyways?

Answer (score 1):

The `highlight_line` setting controls whether or not the current line is highlighted; as seen here it defaults to being turned off:

```
    // If enabled, will highlight any line with a caret
    "highlight_line": false,
```

Regardless of this setting, as in your screenshot the area in the gutter that corresponds to the line that the caret or carets are on will be highlighted so that you can tell where the cursors are. There isn't any corresponding setting for turning off the highlight for the current line though.

One potential solution would be to set `gutter` to `false` to turn off the entire gutter area; that will remove the highlight because there won't be anywhere to display it. However it also removes the line numbers and blocks other functionality like the incremental diff indicators or any package that wants to display icons in the gutter (such as linters).

Presuming that you never want to enable `highlight_line` at all, you can achieve that effect by making a modification to your color scheme so that the same color that's used for the background is also used for the line highlight.

To do that you would create an appropriate `sublime-color-scheme` file in your `User` package, where the `line_highlight` key in the `globals` section has the same value as the `background` key in the source color scheme.

If you're not sure how to do that:

1. Install [PackageDev](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) if you don't already have it installed
2. Choose `PackageDev: Edit Current Color Scheme` from the Command Palette

That will create a new window (similar to how `Preferences > Settings` works) with the contents of your color scheme on the left, and an appropriate override file in your `User` package on the right. If you don't already have such a file in your `User` package, `PackageDev` will use some stub content. The file will have the appropriate name and be set up to save in the appropriate place when you save the file.

If the file in the left pane is of type `sublime-color-scheme` (the newer format), then look for the key named `"globals"`; inside of there will be a key named `background`. For example, in the `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` that ships with Sublime (which is the default color scheme), that section looks like this:

```
    "globals":
    {
        "foreground": "var(white3)",
        "background": "var(black3)",
        "caret": "color(var(white2) alpha(0.9))",
        "block_caret": "color(var(white2) alpha(0.4))",
        "invisibles": "color(var(white3) alpha(0.35))",
        "line_highlight": "var(yellow4)",
        "selection": "var(grey)",
        "selection_border": "var(black2)",
        "misspelling": "var(red2)",
        "active_guide": "color(var(orange2) alpha(0.69))",
        "find_highlight_foreground": "var(black)",
        "find_highlight": "var(orange3)",
        "brackets_options": "underline",
        "brackets_foreground": "color(var(white3) alpha(0.65))",
        "bracket_contents_options": "underline",
        "bracket_contents_foreground": "color(var(white3) alpha(0.65))",
        "tags_options": "stippled_underline"
    },
```

What you would do is copy the key and value for the `background` color, and then paste it into the `"globals"` section in the right hand file and rename from `background` to `line_highlight`. Here the result of that might look like this:

```
{
    // http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html
    "variables": {
        // "green": "#FF0000",
    },
    "globals": {        
        // "foreground": "var(green)",
        "line_highlight": "var(black3)",
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            // "scope": "string",
            // "foreground": "#00FF00",
        },
    ],
}
```

As soon as you make the change and save the file, the color scheme will change and the line highlight is effectively invisible.

If instead the file in the left hand pane is of type `tmTheme` (the older color scheme format inherited from TextMate), the steps are the same but you need to do a little more work.

In that case the source file will be XML (technically an Apple PList file). You'll need to search for the `background` color in the color scheme to see what the color is. That would look something similar to this:

```xml
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#131415</string>
```

In this example, the background color is `#131415`. Using that information, you would create your own `line_highlight` key in the `"globals"` on the right, using that as the color:

```
{
    // http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html
    "variables": {
        // "green": "#FF0000",
    },
    "globals": {
        // "foreground": "var(green)",
        "line_highlight": "#131415",
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            // "scope": "string",
            // "foreground": "#00FF00",
        },
    ],
}
```

Again, as soon as you save the file, the highlight color will change.

Note that regardless of the type of the file in the left hand pane, the file in the right is always a `sublime-color-scheme` file. When Sublime loads your color scheme, it first loads the file from the left hand side, and then it applies the data from the right hand file on top of it.

Thus the result is that you have the exact color scheme as you previously had, and only the parts in your custom file in the `User` package are modified.